# Create FILE* that reads from a variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

We have an external C++ library that takes in a `FILE*` pointer to read some data. Is it possible in C++ to create a `FILE*` pointer that really reads from a string/stream variable? That way, I wouldn't need to write our string contents to a file before then having to open the file using `fopen()` to use the library (or modify the library to add a new constructor).

Comment: Not in standard C or C++, but POSIX gives you `fmemopen`.

Comment: The `FILE` struct is a standard c POSIX feature, and has nothing to do with c++. In c++ you can use `std::stringstream` to do this. But there's no `FILE` implementation that can be used to read from a variable. Maybe this a XY problem, and you missed to clearly explain what's your use case you'll need that for.

Comment: This is likely to be system-dependent. What's your system? By the inclusion of visual-c++ in the tags that would be Windows?

Comment: @dratenik Correct, I'm in Windows. MSVC v142 specifically

Comment: So no fmemopen for you. There is this library https://github.com/Arryboom/fmemopen_windows which discusses possible replacements.

Comment: @dratenik Thanks! So dang, maybe there's no Windows alternative?

Comment: @villapx Nothing that's compatible with `FILE`. Of course Windows supports memory reads through `HANDLE`'s.